# Is an empty block optimized away? C#

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

I am developing a game server in C# and a specific packet gets sent to my server 3 to 5 times per second per player. We will call that packet `PacketA`. I don't do anything with it except make sure that I receive it.

Since this packet gets sent the most, I want to place it first in the switch block so I don't have to make so many unnecessary comparisons. Will the compiler end up optimizing it away anyways (which will cause me to make all the comparisons down the switch block?)

```
switch (packetId)
{
    case PacketID.PacketA: // I do not want to do anything here.
        break;             // Just avoid all other packet id comparisons.

    case PacketID.PacketB:
        HandlePacketB(data);
        break;

    case PacketID.PacketC:
        HandlePacketC(data);
        break;

    // ...

    case PacketID.PacketZ:
       HandlePacketZ(data);
       break;
}
```

If the compiler does optimize this away, how can I change my code so I don't have to check all the other packet ids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `switch` statement in C# is optimized in a way that allows for a very quick evaluation of where to go.  It doesn't read down through the list of options exactly.  Instead it creates a jump list that it optimized for identifying which case to execute.  Here is a link with more information about it:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch-char

Basically, I would suggest that you test the performance of this statement compared to another statement (such as doing an `if` statement for just that first `case` and then doing a `switch` statement if it isn't `PacketA`).  I would imagine that in the end the `switch` statement is the way to go.

If you decide that you want to dig into your app by decompiling it, you can use the new (free) tool from Telerik:

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiling.aspx

Comment: This was going to be my answer. A lot of people recommending using a `Dictionary<TKey, Action>`, unaware that the compiler does this sort of thing internally. I think you won't really see a performance difference either way.

Answer (score 0):

Disassemble your code and check if this case is available.
If it is not availablr then compiler optimized it.

Comment: Mind adding more details about how to disassemble it? Reflector isn't free anymore.

Comment: @icktoofay: `ildasm` comes with VC. If you want to decompile it, check out ILSpy: http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx

Comment: It actually is (they changed the terms for old v6 version, if you have it). Also, there's JetBrains dotPeek, which is free, and ILDASM after all.